# How am i supposed to use a Auth0 with a RESTful api?

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express, auth0

I'm thinking about using Auth0 to signin my users on my nodejs API.

I'm using a MySQL database to sign them in and i also want to use Facebook so they can register and login.

I'm having an issue with the concept of callback, because my API is not supposed to be accessed via a browser. Only a webapp or a mobile app is supposed to access it. How do i have to implement the handling of my signin/login form inputs on my mobile app to use my API which is supposed to use Auth0 ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 comes with a database on the free account. When you add the login registration widget to your application and a user signs up it adds them to the database in your auth0 account.

You can see information about the process [here](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/mysql)

What I do is authenticate users with the auth0 widget. This allows auth0 to handle encryption and security. Then when a user logs in i request a profile in the response. Typically this gives me at least basic info like an email address. I create my own database using the email address as a unique key which allows me to serve the correct data to the user when they login.

Here is an example of my auth0 service using a widget and requesting the user's profile in the response then storing it to local storage.

```
import { Injectable }                      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper }      from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router }                          from '@angular/router';
import { myConfig }                        from './auth.config';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

var options = {
    theme: {
    logo: '/img/logo.png',
    primaryColor: '#779476'
    },
    languageDictionary: {
    emailInputPlaceholder: "email@example.com",
    title: "Login or SignUp"
  }, 
 };

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, options, {});
  userProfile: Object;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.idToken);
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error: any, profile: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.userProfile = profile;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/overview');
      });
      this.lock.hide();
    });
  }

  public login() {
    this.lock.show();
  }

  private get accessToken(): string {
        return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }

  public authenticated(): boolean {
    try {
        var jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
        var token = this.accessToken;
        if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
  }

  public logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    this.userProfile = undefined;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  };
}
```